# What does "Haba Dere Gibt´s a Bier" mean?

Tags: translation, colloquial

I've seen

> Haba Dere Gibt´s a Bier

on t-shirts but can't find a translation. Thanks

Comment: You may watch old movies with actor Hans Moser from the 1920s to early 1960s, and you will have dialogues where a felt 50 per cent of words spoken are "Habe die Ehre".

Comment: To the member who voted "unclear what you're asking": the question in the title can hardly be any clearer than that.

Answer (score 12):

"Habe die Ehre" is a Bavarian/Austrian (and also other region's) greeting when coming or leaving. It literally means "I have the honour" but it means "Hi" when joining a group.

"Haba dere" is the *drunk* version of that: Search for it, there are lots websites with stuff about it. There are even T-shirts with this idiom on it.

"Gibt's a Bier" means "is there beer" / "do you/they have beer here"?

So this is the equivalent of the American English Expression:

> [Wazaa!  Gotta Bud?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgNe8uv4880)

Comment: "Haba Dere" is simply misspelled - either based on lack of knowledge or - if printed on T-shirts - ratheron purpuse in order to draw attention -  for "Habe die Ehre" (meaning as you explained).

Comment: "Habe Dere" is not misspelled, It is written bavarian dialect...

Comment: @Mischa  As there are no "rules" how to write Bavarian, Austrian, or what ever dialect of German, of course, you can claim this. However, if you ask people in Bavaria or Austria to write down "Habe die Ehre" in dialect, they would rather come up with something like "Hobe di Ähre" or so, i.e. something much closer to standard German. "Haba Dere" is purposefully distorted (especially with the capital D remaining from *die* that naturally does not have a capital D), probably with the intent of being funny.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Bavarian is (or should be) only a spoken dialect, there are no official rules to write in this dialect which leads to people write like they speak. In _Niederbayern_ as an example "Habe die Ehre" will be pronounced more like "Haba dere". (Source: The dad of a friend of mine does write "Haba Dere" and sometimes "Habe Dere", so as you can see even one person doesn't always stick to one version)

Comment: i'd rather write "Habe d'Ehre" or "Hawedere", but then I'm Viennese.

Comment: I think it is spelled like this in purpose not to make it too easy to guess for native speakers either. There should me more examples like this, but I can't recall one now.